# vim: how to get filetype in plugin script

Tags: vim, file-type

How do I get the current filetype in a vimscript, say in .vimrc or a regular plugin script?
The line

```
echo &filetype
```

returns an empty string.

Comment: Show us where you use it. In `.vimrc`, no buffers are loaded yet, so it's empty.

Comment: I need it in `.vim/bundles/vim-autoformat/plugin/autoformat.vim`.

Comment: While sourcing (same as with `.vimrc`, it's too early), or inside a function / mapping / command?!

Comment: While sourcing indeed: `let s:formatprgvarname = "g:formatprg_".&filetype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the timing of your plugin. When your plugin script is sourced during the startup of Vim, no buffer has yet been loaded, so `&filetype` is empty. Therefore, something like this

```
let s:formatprgvarname = "g:formatprg_".&filetype
```

does **not** work! (For a *filetype plugin* (in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`), this is different; those are sourced only when the filetype has been detected. But as I understand you want a general-purpose plugin that considers the current filetype.)

Instead, do away with the script-local variable `s:formatprgvarname` and resolve `&filetype` **at the point of action**; i.e. when your autoformat functionality is triggered (by mapping or custom command). If you have no such trigger, you can hook into the `FileType` event and set a (preferably buffer-local) variable then:

```
autocmd FileType * let b:formatprgvarname = "g:formatprg_".&filetype
```

Comment: Is the FileType event also triggered when switching to a buffer with a different filetype?

Comment: No, only when it is initially detected.

Answer (score 5):

In a function:

```
let current_filetype = &filetype
```

On the command line:

```
:echo &filetype
```

`&filetype` is empty when there's no filetype (obviously). If you try to use it when there's no buffer loaded you'll just get nothing.

***edit***

`&filetype` is only useful when you need to know the current filetype in a function executed at runtime when you are editing a buffer.

`&filetype` is only set when a buffer has been determined to be of some filetype. When it is executed, a script (vimrc, ftplugin, whatever) doesn't go through what it would go when it is edited: no filetype checking, no `&filetype`.

An example would be a function that displays the current file in a different external app depending on its filetype. Using `&filetype` in any other context doesn't make sense because it will be empty.

Comment: `&filetype` appears to be empty in the pluginscript for all filetypes like vim and python. (However, in-vim running `:echo &filetype` yields the correct filetype.)

Comment: `&filetype` works at runtime, not in your script. You use `&filetype` in a function that is executed at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there a way to get hold of it in my script? If not, I will have to change the design.

Comment: Did you read my answer? There's no `&filetype` when a `*.vim` script is evaluated because it simply is not relevant at that time. The only situation where you might want to know the filetype of a buffer is when you run a function triggered by an `autocmd` or a `:Command` or a mapping. In such a situation, *just use the first snippet in my answer.* If you want more help you'll have to explain what you are after and possibly show some code.